# View image in cache using FileProvider but file has no extension

Tags: android, xamarin, android-fileprovider

Strange issue.... when I execute an ActionView intent to view whith default gallery app an image located for example in Download folder it's enough to set the correct mime type without the need to specify file extension.

For example look this c# code for xamarin:

```
string myImage = Path.Combine(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "myImage")

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Uri.FromFile(new File(myImage)), "image/jpeg");
StartActivity(intent);
```

This works fine even if *myImage* is a jpeg file with no extension (normally I should use *myImage.jpg*).

But if I want to open the same image located in cache, **using FileProvider to give correct permission**, it doesn't work until I explicitly set the .jpg estension.

```
//Assuming myImage is a valid jpeg just present in cache
string myImage= Path.Combine(CacheDir.AbsolutePath, "myImage");

Uri imageUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", new File(myImage));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.SetDataAndType(imageUri, "image/jpeg");
StartActivity(intent);
```

This does not work, gallery says can't find element.

**But if I rename both file and content variable in *myImage.jpg* the gallery shows the image correctly.**

Since I have to download files of several mime types but with no name I would like to rely only to the specific type avoiding to append file extension.

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Hi, what phone version are your running on? I have tested on 5.0 and 7.0, if you don't use "myImage.jpg", there won't display the image fro your first code, could you please provide a demo? I have put a image on the path `/storage/sdcard/Download/myImage.jpg`. And I am not sure your question, so, the picture can't display if you use the `FileProvider`?

Comment: I have experienced this behavior with both Android 6 and 4.4.4 samsung devices. In practice, put 2 identical images on `/storage/sdcard/Download/myImage.jpg` and `/storage/sdcard/Download/myImage` (last image has no extension). If you run the "inent ActionView" in both setting the content type `image/jpeg` you can see them.
But If instead you put imagese in app cache `/data/data/com.mylab.myapp/cache/myImage.jpg` and `/data/data/com.mylab.myapp/cache/myImage` and use FileProvider to give permission to display them, the second one is not opened.